# Large SQL to MongoDB Transfer?

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, transfer, mariadb

I'm currently in the process of trying to transfer over a million records from SQL to MongoDB (in a completely different schema)

I've coded a Java application that reads data from multiple tables in SQL, copies it to a single new MongoDB document, and uploads it - which is very efficient, and the application takes almost no resources.

However, since there are around a million records that need to be transferred and since we want to minimize downtime (24 hours of downtime during the transfer is unacceptable), we're forced to multi-thread the application. Running with about 200 threads (each doing 3 queries to compile a single BSON document), SQL quickly peaks at 100% cpu use and blocks newly created threads.

My question: What is the best way to prevent this high CPU use?

We already use indexes for anything that it is needed for, and the slowest SQL query runs at 0.0005ms during usual SQL server performance.

In my eyes, it's a waste to shard SQL even though we're about to switch off of it, and reducing the amount of threads really isn't an option. Could transferring entire tables to Mongo then transferring to the schema be a possible alternative? What about moving to SQLLite and getting all SQL data from that (in order to avoid the CPU bottleneck)?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Hard to really comment without a bit more detail on what you are doing to build the documents. Consider adding that to your question. But that does bring to mind, why not build the documents **using** MongoDb? That is, dump one whole table into the collection. Then when iterating another table, augment the existing document **within** the collection. If that is the sort of thing you are doing of course.

Comment: Why is reducing the amount of threads not an option?  You've already stated that "Running with about 200 threads... peaks at 100% cpu use and blocks newly created threads".  This implies you have not selected the correct amount of threads for the workload.  The fact that you're running at 100% CPU use means you're making the most efficient use of the computer that you can, it cannot possibly run faster than that.